# Problem with the returned data by an ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to check if a username is already taken in the database. I used an ajax function. The returned data should be equal to 0 if the username is not taken, and equal to 1 if it's taken. I put a condition with the data to show the two cases with a simple alert but the problem is that the code only executes the first condition even if the username doesn't exist in the database. I don't understand why it doesn't execute the second condition when the data is equal to 0.

**Javascript:**

```
function validarusuario() {
  var Pseudo = $('#Pseudo').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Bienvenu.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      Pseudo: Pseudo
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data != 0) {
        alert('Username already taken');
      } else if (data == 0) {
        alert('Username not taken');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

**PHP:**

```
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    $sBody .= 'errorr<br />';
} else {
    $iNbResult = $stmt->rowCount();
    echo "$iNbResult";            
}
```

When I put `alert(data)` I can see when the data is equal to 0 or to another value so why it doesn't work if I put the data in an if condition?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191769/discussion-on-question-by-huehue-problem-with-the-returned-data-by-an-ajax-funct). If you have advice on how to fix the problem, post an answer. Additional information and responses to clarification questions should be [edit]ed into the question itself, not posted in comments.

Comment: remove quotes `""` from `echo "$iNbResult";` it  should be like this `echo $iNbResult;`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may arise from not checking the type:

```
function validarusuario() {
  var Pseudo = $('#Pseudo').val();
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Bienvenu.php',
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      'Pseudo': Pseudo
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // '==' accepts anything that is not 0 (integer). Zero can be represented by a
      // '0' (string), and in that case '0' != 0 evaluates to TRUE, so the first
      // branch of your if-else is executed.
      if (parseInt(data, 10) !== 0) {
        alert('Username already taken');

      } else if (parseInt(data, 10) === 0) {
        alert('Username not taken');

      }
    }

  })

}
```

In your alert box there's no difference between 0 (integer) and 0 (string) - at least you don't see the difference. But when it comes to JS, it's "something completely different".

If you expect a type of data (string, int, float, Object) you have to check it's type before using it (or try to cast it to that type, and handle errors). **==** and **!=** doesn't check for type, **===** and **!==** does.

You can see the type, if you `console.log(data)`: if in the console you see **"0"**, then it's a `string`, if it's a plain **0**, then it's an `int`.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: I tried your code but it only shows 'Username already taken' even if i use a  username that doesn't exists in the database.

Comment: You may modify “**!== 0**” to “**=== 1**”, and add a default “**else**” branch at the end to **console.log** the actual value. If that doesn’t work, and you still don’t know why, I suggest you add the code that handles your AJAX call to your question description.